# "Visual Query Builder", where is it?

Tags: sql, delphi

I always build my queries by hand, without any tools. Now I want to try the "Visual Query Builder" that comes with Delphi - I have Delphi 2009, xe, xe2 installed. How to start the "Visual Query Builder"? I can't find anything like that in Tools or anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Data Explorer, right-click on a valid connection and select [SQL Window](http://www.scribd.com/doc/67117907/9/SQL-WINDOW-QUERY-BUILDER).

It seems to have been added in Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 0):

you can download it from here: http://www.activequerybuilder.com/download.html
the last link for delphi

Comment: It's already installed with Delphi, but I have no idea how to start it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson same here, but I'm curious to see it.